# How can I make Headings foldable in evil-mode in emacs?

Tags: emacs, markdown, spacemacs

In markdown-mode in insert mode, I can press tab and fold and unfold headings (lines prefixed with #s) but when I'm in normal mode, tab does nothing.

Is there anyway to make tab fold and unfold headings in a similar manner to the insert mode in normal mode?

Answer (score 3):

When in normal mode Evil uses which ever folding package you have. (`show-hide`, `origami`, etc...).

You can then use `z` motions for folding/unfolding. (not `<tab>`)

For example:

- `za` - `evil-toggle-fold`
- `zc` - `evil-close-fold`
- `zr` - `evil-open-folds`
- `zm` - `evil-close-folds`

Answer (score 0):

Adding this binding to your configuration should allow `tab` key in normal mode to toggle fold

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "<tab>") 'evil-toggle-fold)
```